# VoIP on Ubuntu for phones

Tags: ubuntu-touch, voip

Will the new Ubuntu Phone support VoIP through the operating system when out of range of the network the user has? This would be a great way to steal market share from Apple which doesn't support VoIP except through complicated apps.

Comment: Do you mean VoIP server?

Comment: Maybe... I am thinking of when people are outside of cell phone range being able to switch on forwarding to VOIP through the network provider being built into the phone and not having to download an app, I know some phones can do it, and some phones can't. I hope Ubuntu will be able to, kind of like how messaging is set up on Ubuntu without having to download anything special. If that makes sense...

Comment: If they don't have a signal how are they going to connect to the VoIP servers? Will they have wireless internet access?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking they would have Wireless along with cell phone reception so that it could receive calls when out of range of cell reception but in range of a network.

Comment: It would be interesting if they supported SIP out of the box, but they wouldn't be taking market share from anyone else. There are a few really good SIP clients for iPhone, Android, etc.

Comment: I once asked about building qTox: http://askubuntu.com/questions/624395/qtox-voip-on-the-ubuntu-phone

Comment: How about Peer 2 Peer SIP support? We will get device-to-device (D2D) communication from 4G Rel 12 onwards.

Comment: probably not since ubuntu has to find vendors who distribute ubuntu via mobile phones. And they have contacts with telecom providers. And they want to make money.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the default VoIP client for Ubuntu/Ubuntu Phone OS is currently Empathy:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Empathy

In addition to this, someone else was interested in something similar. Unfortunately, they found that VoIP is not a big feature with the current version of Ubuntu's phone os.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296599

The VoIP client appears to work off of 3G/WiFi - type networks. You may have to start a new call after leaving the range of the cellular network. I don't think it's as automatic as you were hoping for, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Ekiga". It's source code is also available if you want to edit it your way. http://www.ekiga.org/

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your answer to include some more information about this program. An excerpt from the link you included and a screenshot would make your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

[Telegram](https://telegram.org/) supports VOIP calls since a few days and as Telegram has been the IM program that has been available from day 1 on Ubuntu Touch, expect it to grow to #1 petty soon.

### :-)